# jquery .load() not working in IE/Safari

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, load

i've got some strange problem when using jquery .load() on my website:

While there is no problem in Chrome/FF/Opera the script just wont work in IE/Safari. It looks like those browsers don't find the php-Script on the Server.

And now its gettin strange: Calling the Script by full qualified path it is suddenly working in IE/Safari but no more in Chrome/FF/Opera.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mainnavi li.sub-li>a, #mainnavi li.top-li>a').mouseover(function(){
    $('#nav_info').empty().show();
    var curSite = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#nav_info').load('/navInfoContent.php', {pageID: curSite});
  });
```

The navInfoContent.php is just some SQL-Query and than echoing HTML-Code

```
echo ('<p>$variable</p>')
```

like this but in correct syntax.

As said, when I change to

```
load('http://www.mydomain.de/navInfoContent.php', {pageID: curSite})
```

it's suddenly working in IE/Safari, but no more in Chrome/FF/Opera. I've allready tried the solution by adding some random stuff to the URL in order to prevent IE from caching, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have the last version of jquery...

.

2nd: define you function in $(document).ready() only when you need. ONLY

Usually, the problem is ready() event.

Comment: THX alot for your tips. Sadly even with jquery1.8.2 and without ready() it still isn't working in IE/Safari